# The number of different multisets

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

There are ${n \choose k}$ ways of choosing $k$ distinct items from a set of size $n$. There  are $n^k$ ways of choosing $k$ items if we allow duplicates. How many distinct multi-sets are there of size $k$?

It must be considerably fewer than $n^k$ as, if the set $S = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ then we say the multi-subsets $\{1,1,2,3\}$ and $\{1,2,1,3\}$, both of size $4$, are the same.

Comment: For each element of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, you have to discuss how many ways you "choose" it. So the answer is the number of solutions to $a_1+\ldots+a_n = k$, and...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called multiset coefficient.

$$\left(\!\!{n\choose k}\!\!\right)=\binom{n+k-1}{k}$$

See here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset_coefficient#Counting_multisets