# multisets in a subset

Tags: combinatorics, multisets

Define $B$ to be a multi-subset of a set $A$ if every element of $B$ is an
element of $A$ and elements of $B$ need not be distinct. The ordering of
elements in $B$ is not important.
 For example, if $A = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $B = \{1,1,3\}$, $B$ is a 3-element
multi-subset of $A$. Also, multi-subset $\{1,1,3\}$ is the same as the
multi-subset $\{1,3,1\}$.

How many 5-element multi-subsets of a 10-element set are
possible? 
And Generalize your result to $m$-element multi-subsets of an $n$- element set $(m < n)$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Aravind I have tried using combinations. For 3-element multi-subset of a 5-element set we have $5 \choose 1 + 5\choose2 * 2! + 5\choose3$. But I can't find any generalisation to higher numbers.

Comment: Ok, this already has an answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620357/the-number-of-different-multisets?rq=1

Comment: Briefly, let $x_i$ be the number of times that $i$ is present. Then what you want is the number of solutions to $x_1+\ldots+x_n=m$ with $x_i \geq 0, x_i \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding it as an answer for closure. It should probably be marked as duplicate as it has an answer on the site, likely many times.
Briefly, let $x_i$ be the number of times that $i$ is present. Then what you want is the number of solutions to $x_1+\ldots+x_n=m$ with $x_i \geq 0, x_i \in \mathbb{Z}$.